# Шаблоны функций. Передача динамического массива в функцию. No matching function for call to

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы, шаблоны-с++

Здравствуйте!
Недавно начал изучать C++, так что заранее извиняюсь за глупые вопросы.На данный момент пытаюсь разобраться, как взаимодействуют массивы с функциями.
Сперва написал простенькую программку, суть которой в следующем: первая функция dec2bin(number) переводит введенное пользователем десятичное число (от 0 до 255) в двоичное, записывает результат в массив с размером 8 и возвращает его. Вторая функция printBiNum_size(biNum, size) выводит этот массив на экран.
Затем стало интересно реализовать функцию, которая бы выводила на экран массив, размер которого заранее неизвестен. В интернете нашел функцию view, реализованную с помощью шаблона, ориентируясь на нее написал свою - printBiNum. Но при попытке передать в функцию массив компилятор выдает ошибку:

> error: no matching function for call to 'printBiNum(int*&)'

Как я понял, это происходит из-за того, что я пытаюсь передать динамический массив, т.к. если передавать массив вида int ar[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} все работает.
**Вопрос:** как нужно изменить функцию printBiNum, чтобы передать в нее динамический массив, не передавая его размер?
Заранее благодарю за любую помощь!
main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "binfun.h"

template <typename T, size_t N>

void printBiNum(const T(&biNum)[N])
{
    for (const auto i: biNum){
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<class T, size_t N>

void view(const T(&arr)[N], const char* name)
{
    std::cout << name <<'[' << N << "] = {";
    for (const auto i: arr)
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << " >;\n";
}
int main()
{
    // Ask for entering a number between 0 and 255, read it
    int number = 193;
    //std::cout << "Please enter a number between 0 and 255: " << factorial(4);
    //int number;
    //std::cin  >> number;

    // Convert number to a binary form
    int *myBiNum = new int[8];
    myBiNum = dec2bin(number);
    // Print binary number
    printBiNum_size(myBiNum, 8);
    int ar[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    printBiNum(ar);
    view(ar, "source array: ar");
    printBiNum(myBiNum);
}
```

binfun.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int* dec2bin(int decNum)
{
    int num_k = decNum;
    int *biNum = new int[8];

    for (int k = 0; k <= 7; ++k){
        int pow2k = 128/pow(2,k);
        if (num_k >= pow2k){
            biNum[k] = 1;
            num_k -= pow2k;
        }
        else{
            biNum[k] = 0;
        }
    }
    return biNum;
    delete [] biNum;
}

void printBiNum_size(int biNum[], int arrSize)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < arrSize; ++k){
        std::cout << biNum[k] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

binfun.h:

```
#ifndef BINFUN_H
#define BINFUN_H

int*  dec2bin(int decNum);
void printBiNum_size(int biNum[], int arrSize);

#endif // BINFUN_H
```

Comment: Слышал про `std::vector`, но пока до него не добрался. С использованием шаблонов это нельзя реализовать? Или же это не имеет смысла в C++?

Comment: @Nikita невозможно. Параметры шаблонов должны быть известны в момент компиляции, а длина динамического массива не может быть известна на этапе компиляции.

Comment: @retorta благодарю за доступное объяснение! Пойду читать про `std::vector`.

Comment: Размер массива тут как раз таки известен на стадии компиляции (по крайней мере согласно тому, что пока написано). Поэтому не ясно, при чем здесь `std::vector`. Если размер действительно известен, то если уж и пользоваться стандартным классом-оболочкой, то `std::array`, а не `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать такую функцию вы сможете только в том случае, если размер массива известен на стадии компиляции. Согласно тому, что у вас пока написано, этот размер вам действительно известен на стадии компиляции, а проблема заключается в потере типа "массив" при использовании оператора `new []`.

Да, оператор `new[]`, к сожалению, не позволяет сохранит оригинальный "массивный" тип в получаемом результате. Этот оператор всегда возвращает указатель на *элемент* массива, а не на весь массив.

Поэтому сохранения "массивного" типа вам придется выкручиваться либо через явное приведение типа

```
 int (*myBiNum)[8] = (int (*)[8]) new int[8];

 for (unsigned i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
   (*myBiNum)[i] = i;

 printBiNum(*myBiNum);

 delete [] (int *) myBiNum;
```

либо через варианты вида

```
 int (*myBiNum)[8] = new int[1][8];

 for (unsigned i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
   (*myBiNum)[i] = i;

 printBiNum(*myBiNum);

 delete [] myBiNum;
```

Если же вы вместо "голого" массива хотите воспользоваться стандартным классом-оболочкой и размер действительно известен на стадии компиляции, то более уместным будет использование `std::array`, а не `std::vector`.

Comment: Если все средства хороши, то можно и std::bitset. Он и из числа сам прочитает. И строку вернет.